# Error while dowloading excel file using mysql data using PHPExcel

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I am trying to convert **MYSQL** data into **Excel** using **PHPExcel** but it show below error.

> SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
>   [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Comment: Actually my code is working with small data but this error come when i am trying to download large amount of data.

Comment: try increase your php execution time in php.ini file

Comment: Check the server logs: most likely causes are hitting a memory limit or a timeout

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); this line of code work for me